# From dvi file to the latex code

Tags: forward-inverse-search, dvi-mode

I have remember that my friend told me that I can just click a line in the `*.pdf`, then latex will direct me to the corresponding line in the latex code. I have tried this function when I am using WinEdt 10. When I press the key `Ctrl shift + X`, I can compile my code and read it in `dvi`. format, when I click the content in `dvi`, it can not direct me to the latex code but the Texwork file come out. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure `Yap` to link to WinEdt?

[image]

[image]